# Convert for loop to a while loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I've been trying to convert the following JS code that uses a for loop to a while loop and/or do-while loop.

```
var unique = function(array) 
{
  var newArray = []
  array.sort()
  for(var x in array) if(array[x] != array[x-1]) newArray.push(array[x])
  return newArray
}
```

The code is suppose to return only distinct names from an array of names that repeat. I've been trying to convert the for loop but so far I've been running into problems using this:

```
do
{
    newArray.push(array[x])
}
while(array[x] != array[x-1])
return newArray;
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Note that using for..in with an array may not return properties in the sequence you expect, whereas *push* will add them to the new Array in the sequence they are discovered (i.e. the returned array might be in a different "order" to the original). You may also discover other properties that don't have a numeric index.

Answer (score 1):

Is it guaranteed that your names are only going to be duplicated in sequence i.e. is it true that if a name does have a duplicate it will be directly after it? If not, then checking the elements that are directly next to each will not find all the duplicates. You'll have to do a nested for loop or some other n^2 algorithm.

```
var duplicated = false;
for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
    {
        if (array[x] == array[y])
        {
            duplicated = true;
        }
    }
    if (!duplicated)
    {
        array.push(array[x]);
    }
    duplicated = false;
}
return newArray;
```

please note, this implementation is very poor but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. The following preserves the original sequence:

```
function getUnique(array) {
  var newArray = array.slice(); // copy original
  var i = newArray.length - 1;

  do {
      if (newArray[i] == newArray[--i]) {
        newArray.splice(i, 1);
      }
  } while(i)

  return newArray;
}
```

Note that the above assumes a sorted, contiguous array (no missing members). If you can't be sure of that, sort *newArray* before the *do..while* loop and maybe compact it to make it contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop doesn't make sense for your use case.  A `while` loop is good when you want to loop as long as some condition is met and then stop the first time it fails.  But a `for` loop is good when you want to loop through a certain number of items (for instance all of them).

So stick with a `for` loop.  Also a few notes on `while` loops for whenever you do use them:

A `for` loop automatically updates the loop index which in your case is `x`.  A `while` loop doesn't.  So, to replicate your `for` loop, you would need to manually increment `x`.

Also, you test at the top of the `for` loop.  To mirror that behavior you would want a `while` instead of a `do`- `while` (`while` tests before executing each loop, `do`-`while` tests after).

But if you used a while loop, you'd exit the loop the first time `array[x] != array[x-1]` failed.  And it sounds like you don't want that.  You want to push all values that meet that test.