# Changing a for loop to a while loop, average of dice rolls

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me write this function as a while loop instead of a for loop?

```
function RollAverage(){
  //assumes: outputDiv is available for output
  //results: counts rolls and averages them
  var userNum,countTotal,rollSum;
  userNum=parseFloat(document.getElementById('textBox').value);
  countTotal=0;
  for (rollSum=0; countTotal<userNum; countTotal=countTotal++){
    rollSum=rollSum+(RandomInt(1,6) + RandomInt(1,6));
    countTotal++;
  } 
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML='Heres the average ' +(rollSum/countTotal);
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried with `while`, and then people can help you with debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert for loop to a while loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531096/convert-for-loop-to-a-while-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any specific library for RandomInt() ? I have used instead
Math.floor(Math.random(1,6) and modified the code for while loop as below:

```
function RollAverage(){
var userNum,countTotal,rollSum;
userNum=parseFloat(document.getElementById('textone').value);
countTotal=0;
rollSum=0;
while (countTotal < userNum){
 rollSum = rollSum + (Math.floor(Math.random(1,6) + Math.random(1,6)));
    countTotal++;
 }
document.getElementById('myDivId').innerHTML =(rollSum/countTotal);
}
```

Full working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/b805pkcv/) code here